# Is it necessary to use ('http://localhost:3000/users/' + id) structure, when fetching Individual Data by ID with useParams( )?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use useParams() in right way

but I have doubts about useParams() structure.

is it compulsory to use ( ' ' + id) or ( " " + id)

```
const { id } = useParams();
const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/users/' + id)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            setItem(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

or can we do like this with backticks ` ` ?

```
const { id } = useParams();
const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            setItem(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

are they same or is there any difference ? How does it affects to output ?

I tried both these ways

Comment: This has very little to do with react or axios, but yes they are 2 different ways to make strings in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String